# Decoding base64/quoted-printable attachment from Gmail

Tags: gmail, outlook, attachment

Sometimes, mostly Outlook users, sends me an email message with another email message embedded in it. It is done in Outlook by dragging an existing email message into the window where you're composing a new message.

In Gmail I can see that message has a text attachment called "noname". This is how the attachment look in Gmail:

[image: How it looks at Gmail]

How can I see this attached message properly without resorting to pasting the encoded text to base64 decoding [websites](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) or [software](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/base64-decode.1.html)?

PS:
The attachment typically has the following headers:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0013_01CB4A23.7DCA45B0"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0
thread-index: ActIHzbBfL+0XRcRSySKQ19sBYlC+g==

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_0013_01CB4A23.7DCA45B0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

...

------=_NextPart_000_0013_01CB4A23.7DCA45B0
Content-Type: text/html;
    boundary="=======AVGMAIL-12161015=======";
    charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

...

------=_NextPart_000_0013_01CB4A23.7DCA45B0--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very late answer, but I happen to use this all the time.

On windows, super simple. Save the message with extension .b64 and open it in for example winzip. Now you can view the content of the message in internal viewer or extract it

In gMail you can "view original" to get at just the b64 part

Comment: I was hoping it is possible without additional software.

Comment: Not that I know of. But you fail to mention WHERE you want to see it. gMail shows it ok for you, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Outlook (or, probably Windows Mail) installed, try this:

- Download "noname"
- Rename as "noname.eml"
- File Icon should change, and you can doubleclick to open it.

This has always worked for me flawlessly.